# launch stereo_image_proc and image topic names

Tags: roslaunch, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all;

I have a bag with stereo images topics and I am trying now to create a launch for stereo_image_proc.
The topics I have to perform stereo are:

```
/cameras_pan_tilt/left/camera_info         
/cameras_pan_tilt/left/image                    
/cameras_pan_tilt/right/camera_info        
 /cameras_pan_tilt/right/image
```

The namespace is obviously "cameras_pan_tilt", but the images do not have the default name "image_raw".
I am trying to create a simple launch to adjust parameters, but I have the following problems:

1.- the images in image view, are not displayed.

2.- I do not for sure if the remapping is correct for stereo_image_proc to process everything.

The launch is as follows, following tutorials:

```
<launch>    
        <node ns="cameras_pan_tilt" pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc" name="stereo_image_proc" output="screen">
            <remap from="left/image" to="left/image_raw"/>
            <remap from="right/image" to="right/image_raw"/>
        </node>
    
        <node pkg="image_view" type="stereo_view" name="stereo_view">
            <remap from="cameras_pan_tilt" to="stereo"/>
            <remap from="image_rect" to="image"/>
        </node>

        <node pkg="rqt_reconfigure" type="rqt_reconfigure" name="rqt_reconfigure"/>
</launch>
```

I receive also the following warnings:

```
[ WARN] [1440760099.284773259]: The input topic '/cameras_pan_tilt/left/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1440760099.284920490]: The input topic '/cameras_pan_tilt/right/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1440760159.286287583]: The input topic '/cameras_pan_tilt/left/image_raw' is not yet advertised
```

Could anyone please help me with this issue, to launch stereo_image_proc from a launch to reconfigure?
Thank you all very much in advance,

Best regards,

Alberto

EDIT:

After changing the fields "from" and "to" in the remap fields in the launch file, that error has disappeared, but I still see no images with image view, and in addition I have new error. Any possible clue?

```
[ WARN] [1441003721.212940511]: [image_transport] Topics '/cameras_pan_tilt/left/image_mono' and '/cameras_pan_tilt/left/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
    Image messages received:      15
    CameraInfo messages received: 50
    Synchronized pairs:           0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216693/launch-stereo_image_proc-and-image-topic-names/) by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try swapping your remaps in `stereo_image_proc` so that they read:

```
<remap from="left/image_raw" to="left/image"/>
<remap from="right/image_raw" to="right/image"/>
```

When you remap topics for a node you are remapping from what is *expected* by the node to what you are *providing*. The `stereo_image_proc` node *expects* to receive `image_raw`, but you are *providing* `image`. That should get rid of the warnings that are printed by `stereo_image_proc` about input topics not being advertised yet.

Once `stereo_image_proc` has the correct input topics then it will start to publish rectified images, a disparity image, and a point cloud. You will need to swap the first remap in `image_view/stereo_view` as well. That should also fix your issue with `image_view/stereo_view`.

EDIT (for new question):
Take a look at the [stereo_image_proc parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc). The `stereo_image_proc` node assumes all input messages are exactly synchronized with respect to the timestamps in their headers. Inside the node tags add:

```
<param name="approximate_sync" value="true"/>
<param name="queue_size" value="10"/>
```

This will help if you do not have hardware triggering/syncing of your `image_raw` and `camera_info` topics.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2015-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on 2015-08-31**:
Perfect !!! That was it !!
Really, thanks a lot !